# Add image to DataGridView using DataGridViewImageColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I am trying to add an image in a `DataGridView` using the following code

```
DataGridViewImageColumn Editlink = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
Image image = Image.FromFile("Images\\Edit.png");
Editlink.Image = image;
Editlink.HeaderText = "Edit";
Editlink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
Editlink.Width = 40;
```

In the above code

`Image image = Image.FromFile("Images\\Edit.png");`

It throws an error saying

> File not found

When I changed the `FromFile` path to `"C:\\Test\\Images\\Edit.png"`, it works.

How can I achieve the same result without using actual path?

Comment: The path is relative to the working directory of your application.

Comment: It seems this is what you are looking for: [Adding clickable image/button to datagridview in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253732/adding-clickable-image-button-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Please use Add Resource to add Images to local Resource folder and then call it by file name.

The question is a duplicate of this 
[filenotfound-when-i-use-image-fromfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729873/filenotfound-when-i-use-image-fromfile)